# Prove that every subset of $A$ is a subsemigroup of $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

> Let $n\ge 2$ be a natural number, and $A$ be a semigroup with **more than $2$ elements**. Let every subset of $A$ with **n elements** is a subsemigroup of A. Prove that every subset of $A$ is a subsemigroup of $A$.

If $n=2$ the answer is clear. But what if $n>2$ since we don't know either $A$ finite or not?

Comment: Presumably we have $|A|>n$?

Comment: The 2 element sets can be obtained as intersections of bigger sets, and the intersection of subsemigroups is subsemigroup.

Comment: @Berci Not necessarily. See my comment above.

Comment: @Arthur i think Berci is right. Yes, |A|>n and any subset of A has at least 2 elements. If that subset has only 2 elements x and y so x*y=x or x*y=y. In any case it is a semigroup. If we have n>2, see Berci's comment